# books containing leelas of mother saraswati

Tags: book-recommendation

Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva are probably most famous in Hindu stories, but I'd like to also know if there are any books like the upanishads that describe the leelas of mother Saraswati?

Comment: There is a Tantric form of Goddess Saraswati known as Goddess Matangi. I think there should be some Tantra book on her.

Comment: Are you looking for any particular language version like English or Hindi?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto , anything at all that tells the vedic or ancient stories of mother , i.e. one that is not based on human imagination

Comment: There is no dedicated authentic book for Devi Saraswati. She appears in Devi-Bhagavata Purana, Rig Vida, and few other. As stated in answer there is this medieval text alone. Actually, Saraswati is a personal of veda themselves. So, it is more or else symbolic in nature.

Comment: @UbiBhatt , what is the devi bhagwat purana? Is it different from bhagwat gita?

Comment: Sorry for using wrong word in my previous comment. It is not "personal", but actually I mean to say " Personification". And yes, devi bhagwat puran and bhagwat gita are two different books.

Comment: @UbiBhatt , what's the difference between the two books? If you have read them can you give me a slight hint?

Comment: Devi bhagwat - talks about feminine power to be ultimate. Whereas, Gita (song) is ultimate knowledge or it is a ooze of all Upanishads & vedas.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is [Sarasvati-rahasya Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarasvati-rahasya_Upanishad) which means “the Secret Knowledge of the Wisdom Goddess” This is the medieval era text and one of the minor Upanishads of Hinduism. It is classified under the eight Shakta Upanishads and  Krishna Yajurveda. It's text worships Sarasvati form of Shakti which is Hindu goddess of arts, music and learning.

These manuscripts are also entitled as Sarasvati Upanisad, Saraswati Rahasyopnisad, Sarasvatyupanishad and Sarasvatirahasyopanisad.

Comment: is it only a few pages: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/sarasvati_upan.pdf ?(the saraswati rashasyaupanishad) or is there a more story form ? A bit larger text perhaps?

Comment: Yes..it is complete 47 verses in total..you can check its complete english translation here http://www.astrojyoti.com/sarasvatirahasyaupanishad-3.htm

Comment: do you happen to know anything of the story where rishi Durvasha cursed mother saraswati .... I was also looking for that story of which I only remember little since I had seen it somewhere years ago ......... I wonder if the story belongs to some upanishads?

Comment: Are you talking of Sage Durvasa’s curse to Goddess Saraswati to be born as a human being?

Comment: I just remember the part that he gave the curse, since I saw this many years ago I sort of have forgotten. But it seems you happen to know of it and there must have been a story that followed (maybe in a book perhaps?). Could you please include that in your answer?

Comment: I only remember this much..will share the link here..if I find somewhere

Comment: hey..you can find something in this..https://adziesinghviews.blogspot.com/2019/01/relationship-between-brahma-saraswati.html

Comment: I find the blog confusing though , all sort of things mentioned by the author and not mentioned  about the story of durvasa cursing mother. I also searched all around and not a single mention of it anywhere.

Comment: I came across this book: https://www.bookganga.com/eBooks/Books/Details/4626152627505790987 , what do you think of it? Its in marathi else would have loved to get it

Comment: Thankyou..but I can't read marathi